# Difference between Internal and External RTC

Tags: embedded, hardware, time, soc, system-on-chip

what is the difference between internal and external RTC ?

Comment: The internal in built into something and  the external needs to be separately connected to something. You must be more specific.

Comment: happy - This is a duplicate of your previous question which was "[closed](/help/closed-questions)", waiting for you to edit that one and add more detail. Duplicating the same question is not allowed, as it bypasses the quality control mechanism of closing questions which need to be improved. If you want more help, you should *edit your previous question* and answer the requests for clarification asked in comments there. Thanks. (Do not ask yet more new questions on this topic.)